# Dev/sda5 clean #/# files, #/# blocks after upgrading from 1804 to 1910. Stuck on same numbers even after waiting overnight

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade

I dual-booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu with UNetbootin and after upgrading from 18.04 to 19.10 from that Ubuntu installation, it says: `dev/sda5 clean ####/#### files ######/###### blocks`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: There is no supported way to upgrade from 18.04 to 19.10. How did you do it and why?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just resolved this. Tried tons of other methods, but the only one that really fixed it was by doing the following :

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

From a terminal (for example through the recovery mode from GRUB )

Comment: You fixed what? Was it your question?

Comment: I'm responding to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240230/dev-sda5-clean-files-blocks-after-upgrading-from-1804-to-1910-stuck-on/1241119?noredirect=1#comment2091180_1241119